# create-react-app is not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am a regular react user and usually use create-react-app but from this morning it is not working.
I have checked the npm, it is installed and fine. I have checked that create-react-app is globally installed on my system. The error is coming with some JSON file.

Versions installed on my system:
node -v
v9.0.0

$ npm -v
5.5.1

I have attached the log file below, I'm attaching log file from where the error comes first:

```
 917 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex 19ms (from cache)
918 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@^6.22.0 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....7":{"name":"babel-pl'
919 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@^6.22.0 fetched in 25ms
920 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.24.1 checking installable status
921 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@^6.22.0 fetched in 24ms
922 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.22.0 checking installable status
923 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@^6.22.0 fetched in 23ms
924 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@6.24.1 checking installable status
925 silly pacote range manifest for babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@^6.23.0 fetched in 24ms
926 silly resolveWithNewModule babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.23.0 checking installable status
927 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....7":{"name":"babel-pl'
927 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
927 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
927 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
927 verbose stack     at <anonymous>
927 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
928 verbose cwd C:\Users\ashve\Desktop\Startup\startup
929 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
930 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts"
931 verbose node v9.0.0
932 verbose npm  v5.5.1
933 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '....7":{"name":"babel-pl'
934 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to fix this so far?

Comment: @CollinD I have reinstalled the create-react-app, checked for npm version. Everything seems fine.

Comment: I use create-react-app all the time, and I'd love to help. However, simply dumping a portion of a log file is not an appropriate question for this forum. Will you please edit your question with a small reproducible example of your problem, along with ideas or things you have tried?

Comment: @MichaelJasper Okay. I m adding some photos.

Comment: show your package.json please

Comment: While I wouldn't expect a reproducible version for this, package version and Node version would help

Comment: @seethrough How am I suppose to open package.json file when nothing is getting created. You get that what I'm saying?

Comment: Have you tried `npm cache clean` and if that does not work `npm cache clean --force` ?

Comment: @devserkan Ya I just did that. it's working now. I'm waiting for the entire process to be done. If it'll then probably you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw you're using Windows. Try to clean the cache.

```
 npm cache clean --force
```

or

Goto `%appdata%\npm-cache` and check if the directory is clean or not. If not, delete all file from the directory manually.

Now try `create-react-app yourAppName`